# Approximate intersection of $3$ or more hyperbolas

Tags: linear-algebra, multivariable-calculus

I have $3$ audio sensors located on the vertices of a triangle which has co-ordinates as $(X_1,Y_1) (X_2,Y_2) (X_3,Y_3)$.  A signal is emitted from a source @location $(x,y)$. Let the speed of the signal be ‘$S$’. The time taken to reach each sensor be $t_1,t_2,t_3$ respectively. Now, physically I can measure $t_1-t_2$ , $t_2-t_3$ , $t_3-t_1$. Using these time differences I want to locate the signal source. I get three equations for path difference for each pair of sensors as shown below:

$$\sqrt{(x-X_1)^2+(y-Y_1)^2}-\sqrt{(x-X_2)^2+(y-Y_2)^2}=(t_1-t_2)S \\ \sqrt{(x-X_2)^2+(y-Y_2)^2}-\sqrt{(x-X_3)^2+(y-Y_3)^2}=(t_2-t_3)S \\ \sqrt{(x-X_3)^2+(y-Y_3)^2}-\sqrt{(x-X_1)^2+(y-Y_1)^2}=(t_3-t_1)S$$

Theoretically these three hyperbola's should intersect at a single point, but due to noise in the measurement's they might deviate slightly and not sure to be able to intersect at a single point which is the location of a signal source. Now, my problem is how do I calculate analytically or using numerical methods the approximate point where these equations almost intersect. We can get solution only using two of those equations, but in case of multiple solutions I want to make sure which one the appropriate one using the third one. So kindly guide me in this case.

Comment: Related: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Artillery_sound_ranging

Comment: You can use nonlinear least squares (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-linear_least_squares). You select a candidate point (most likely previous known position) and linearize around it using the Jacobian and iteratively approach to the correct location. I have experience with this method and it works pretty good if you can avoid numerical issues with NLS.